# Отправление фотографий ВКонтакте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

**Моя задача:** у меня есть *url* фотографий. Мне нужно отправить их в личные сообщения человеку через сообщество.

Почитав, я пришел к выводу, что нельзя напрямую отправлять фотографии и напрямую загружать на сервер. Но как мне загрузить фотографию в ВК с компьютера? Могу ли я напрямую её загружать в сообщения или мне нужно грузить её в альбом паблика, а затем получать её id и с ним отправлять?

P.S. Я использую `import vk_api`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мой вариант загрузки и отправки фотографии в личные сообщения от имени сообщества. Реализован алгоритм, описанный в [официальной документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=4.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

```
import vk_api
import requests

# Задаём переменные
group_id = 'ID' # ID группы, без "-"
access_token = 'TOKEN' # access_token, который мы получили в группе
api_version = '' # Ваша версия API
filename = 'путь до картинки'

# Авторизуемся в VK
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=access_token, api_version=api_version)
api = vk_session.get_api()

# Получаем адрес сервера для загрузки картинки
upload_url = api.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(group_id=group_id, v='5.131')['upload_url']

# Формируем данные параметров для сохранения картинки на сервере
request = requests.post(upload_url, files={'photo': open(filename, "rb")})
params = {
    'server': request.json()['server'],
    'photo': request.json()['photo'],
    'hash': request.json()['hash'],
    'group_id': group_id,
    'v': api_version
}

# Сохраняем картинку на сервере и получаем её идентификатор
photo_id = api.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(**params)[0]['id']

# Формируем параметры для отправки картинки в ЛС и отправляем её
params = {
    'user_id': ID, # ID пользователя, которому мы должны отправить картинку
    'random_id': 0,
    'message': 'Привет, вот твоя картинка!',
    'attachment': f'photo-{group_id}_{photo_id}',
    'v': api_version
}
api.messages.send(**params)
```

UPD: Используемую версию API *(api_version)* необязательно передавать. Также данный код скорее всего будет использоваться для бота, который имеет клавиатуру, поэтому стоит добавить в `params` `'keyboard': key`, где *key* - это ваша клавиатура, которую вы передаете пользователю.

Comment: Спасибо, оно мне помогло, только пришлось переделать метод под другие задачи.

Comment: Если не передавать используемую версию API *(api_version)*, то в некоторых случаях при запросе к API может вылетать ошибка, поэтому я её и вставил в пример :)

Comment: Я и написал, что делать это необязательно. Все функции, которые я использую, этого не требуют.

Comment: А, хорошо, понял.